# Getting number of Excel sheets using apache tika

Tags: java, excel, apache-tika

While extracting excel content using apache tika I can extract content from the first sheet only. How can I find the total number of sheets? The code I used is shown below.

```
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\ExtractExcel\\test.xlsx"));
ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
OOXMLParser msofficeparser = new OOXMLParser();
msofficeparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only process certain sheets, you'll need to call Apache Tika in a way that outputs HTML. You can see one way to do that in the [Apache Tika *Parsing to XHTML* example](http://tika.apache.org/1.8/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML). If you do that, you'll see that the XHTML you get from an Excel file is along the lines of

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="meta:last-author" content="RIBEN9"/>
<meta name="dcterms:modified" content="2007-10-01T16:31:43Z"/>
<title>Simple Excel document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="page"><h1>Feuil1</h1>
   <table><tbody><tr>   <td>Sample Excel Worksheet - Numbers and their Squares</td></tr>
   <tr> <td/></tr>
   </tbody></table>
   </div>
   <div class="page"><h1>Feuil2</h1>
   <table><tbody><tr>   <td/></tr>
   </tbody></table>
   </div>
</body></html>
```

As you can see, each sheet is in its own `<div class="page">` section, so you can split by that

If you look at the Tika example for [Fetching just certain bits of the XHTML](http://tika.apache.org/1.8/examples.html#Fetching_just_certain_bits_of_the_XHTML), you'll see how to go about pulling out just one sheet